# How to specify a relative date in yaml fixtures for RoR unit tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, yaml

I'm writing unit test using fixtures in yaml for a ruby on rails project.

We have many tests for users being `<` or `>` to `n` year old.
ex:

```
young_kid:
  id: 2
  firstname: Nano
  lastname: Shinonome
  email: imarobot@nichijou.jp
  birthdate: 2000-05-11
```

Is there a way to specify a relative date like `2.days.from_now` So that our tests are not bound to fail once the threshold is reached ?

We're using vanilla RoR unit tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dynamic fixture data, you are best off using [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails).

However, for your tests in question, you could use the the [Timecop gem](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) to fix the time during your test. Here's how your unit test might look with Timecop:

```
Timecop.freeze(Date.new(2018, 5, 11, 0, 0, 0)) do
  assert young_kid.birthdate < 18.years.ago
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to specify relative dates in your fixtures yaml file. Do this...

```
young_kid:
  ...
  birthdate: <%= 2.days.from_now.to_date.to_s(:db) %>
```

A side note that fixtures are loaded really early in the test lifecycle so freezing time (using something like the Timecop gem) in your test setup block occurs **after** the relative dates in the fixtures get loaded, meaning that relative dates in your fixtures will always be relative to today.

This has the effect of severely limiting the usefulness of freezing time in your test.